# MySQL SUM column1 if column2 equals today and column3 equals specific test

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, sum

I was cruising along setting up a production schedule at work, but I have been stuck on something that seems like it should be so easy.

I have a table called orders with columns for date, item and quantity.

I am trying to total the quantity of each item for a specific date.

I've been stuck for hours trying all sorts of things. Not sure if I am even close.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date_prod='2011-10-01' AS 'today';
SELECT item, date_prod, SUM( quantity )
FROM today
GROUP BY item
HAVING date_prod = '2011-10-01'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Tried playing around a bunch already. VIEW is not a practical way for me to do this because I want to be able to query a specific date far into the future and see what the total quantity is for each item ordered that day.

Something tells me this should be easy but I'm pretty new at this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SELECT item,date_prod,SUM(IF(date_prod='2011-10-01'), quantity, 0) FROM orders seems even easier but it still doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT item, SUM( quantity ) AS total
FROM orders
WHERE date_prod = '2011-10-01'
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked perfectly.  I really appreciate it, I'm finally unstuck!  And it was all so simple in hindsight.